# How can i solve The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing. Django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to catagorize my posts.

```
def katagori_girisim(request):
cg = IlanKatagoriGirdi.objects.filter(katagoriler='Girisimci Mentorlugu')
katagiri = IlanSayfa.objects.filter(ilan_katagori=cg)
return render(request, 'pages/katagori_girisim.html', {'katagiri':katagiri})
```

I wrote this code in view. And I wrote this in template:

```
{% for girisimilan in katagiri %}
          <div class="card">
              <img src="/media/{{ girisimilan.ilan_foto }}" class="card-img-top img-fluid"  style="width: 25rem; height: 15rem;" alt="ilan_foto">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{ girisimilan.ilan_baslik }}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text text-center">{{ girisimilan.ilan_aciklama }}</p>
                  </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

But I am getting the error in the title.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first method like:

```
IlanKatagoriGirdi.objects.filter(katagoriler='Girisimci Mentorlugu').first()
```

Or you can use slicing like this:

```
IlanKatagoriGirdi.objects.filter(katagoriler='Girisimci Mentorlugu')[:1]
```

This will not give error if the query returns no element